# Question answered before it was asked

Tags: bug, questions, answers

How can it be that some question have answers whose creation date is earlier than the creation date of the question?

See this [data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/357639):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM Posts PA
JOIN Posts PQ ON PQ.Id = PA.ParentId
WHERE PA.PostTypeId = 2
AND DATEDIFF(S, PQ.CreationDate, PA.CreationDate) < 0
```

Or this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters).

[image]
[image]

Maybe there is a bug?

Comment: If you look at the edit history, you'll see the question-merge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is caused by question merges.

If an newer question is designate as the master, the answers of the older question(s) could have a creation date earlier than the master question.

This is very much by design.

There are several cases [like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168201/158100) as answered by [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238448/why-are-there-posts-with-votes-cast-before-their-creation-date/238450#238450) with an answer from [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357646) that list all questions with that effect

Comment: Don't you mean the opposite? If a newer question is the master, then we have answers from the older question being merged in.